# Need a vertical scroll in nvd3 multiBarHorizontalChart if no. of bars increases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

am using NVD3 to get multiBarHorizontalChart. I would required to draw the same with more no of bars (around 100). With increase in no. of bars, the bar size decreases and get adjusted into the container. However I would require the bar size to be static and need an internal scroll for the bars and Y axis

Comment: you are using angular nvd3?

Comment: yes am using Angular nvd3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it ! Had 2 divs: one for chart, y axis and legend and other specifically for x axis, removed the X-axis from nvd3's svg and appended the same to separate div. Added scroll to the div which holds nvd3's svg.

```js
d3.select("#forXaxis").append(function() {
    var xaxis=  d3.selectAll('.nvd3').selectAll('.nv-y').attr('transform', 'translate(10,0)').remove();
    console.log("Appending "+xaxis[0][0]);
    return xaxis[0][0];
   });
```

```css
.chart-container{
   width:80%;
   height:500px;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="chart-container">
  <div class="charter" style = "height:300px; width:500px; border:1px solid red;overflow-y:auto;"> 
   <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
  </div> 
  <div class= "for-xaxis"><svg id = "forXaxis" width="100%" height="80px"></svg></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Great that you achieved:)

Answer (score 1):

You manually have two divs and adjust through css,

```
 <div class="outerdiv">
      <div class="innerdiv">
        <nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="inner"></nvd3>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/hOoTPfMZ8TrjHy1xH80q?p=preview)

Comment: But still the chart is not scrollable in your demo.. I require some thing like [this](http://codepen.io/ahmohamed/pen/mJJqyL?editors=1010) with angular nvd3

Comment: @SureshPMS I dont see a scrollbar in your sample

Comment: there would be a vertical scroll bar at the left. Anyways thanks  a lot for your time. Appreciate it :) I have achieved and posted the solution.